# gremlin hasId should be equivalent to id().is(xxx) in apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.3.4-bin.zip

Tags: spring-data, gremlin

From my understanding of hasId step, it should be the same behavior to id().is() step. Which means the follow script should print the same result.

```
g.V().hasId(4)
g.V().id().is(4)
```

But unfortunately, the hasId() step seems not work as I expected, is there any something wrong from my side ? the whole script in below FYI.

```
gremlin> g.addV('Orange').property('price', '1.79').property('location', 'location-0').property('_classname', 'com.microsoft.spring.data.gremlin.common.domain.Orange')
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.V().id().is(0)
==>0
gremlin> g.V().id()
==>0
==>4
gremlin> g.addV('Orange').property('price', '1.79').property('location', 'location-0').property('_classname', 'com.microsoft.spring.data.gremlin.common.domain.Orange')
==>v[8]
gremlin> g.V().id()
==>0
==>4
==>8
gremlin> g.V().hasId(8)
gremlin> g.V().id().is(8)
==>8
```

Answer (score 4):

You're running into an inconsistency in your graph's handling of ids and I assume that the graph you are using is TinkerGraph. It's default configuration for `id` lookups is to compare via `equals()` so, using your example, you can see what's going on:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasId(0)
gremlin> g.V().hasId(0L)
==>v[0]
```

So why does this work then:

```
gremlin> g.V().id().is(0)
==>0
```

For that answer, we compare the `profile()` of each traversal:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasId(0L).profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[0])                                            1           1           0.755   100.00
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -           0.755        -
gremlin> g.V().id().is(0).profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[])                                             2           2           0.063    29.62
IdStep                                                                 2           2           0.089    41.73
IsStep(eq(0))                                                          1           1           0.061    28.65
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -           0.214        -
```

They compile to two different traversals. The first shows that the `hasId()` is optimized to a single `TinkerGraphStep` with the `id` applied to it which means it uses an index lookup (and thus `equals()`). On the other hand, when you use `is()` in the fashion that you are, the TinkerGraph query optimizer doesn't make note of that and simply uses a linear scan of ids and a in-memory filter with `IsStep`. `IsStep` is smarter about numbers comparisons than `TinkerGraphStep` is and it just knows that a "0" is a "0" and ignores the type.

You can get the same behavior from TinkerGraph though if you reconfigure its `IdManager` as discussed in [Practical Gremlin](http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#ld) and the [Reference Documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuration_3):

```
gremlin> conf = new BaseConfiguration()
==>org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration@2c413ffc
gremlin> conf.setProperty("gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager","LONG")
gremlin> conf.setProperty("gremlin.tinkergraph.edgeIdManager","LONG")
gremlin> conf.setProperty("gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexPropertyIdManager","LONG");[]
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open(conf)
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('Orange').property('price', '1.79').property('location', 'location-0').property('_classname', 'com.microsoft.spring.data.gremlin.common.domain.Orange')
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V(0)
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V().hasId(0)
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V().id().is(0)
==>0
```

Comment: Thanks for explain with details, I think it is little tricky here. If we leverage IdManager to ANY, the scenario may be more complicated.

Comment: The reason we default to `ANY` is mostly a historic one. In earlier versions of TinkerPop 1.x and 2.x TinkerGraph worked in this fashion. We only introduced the concept of an `IdManager` in 3.x and to maintain the feel of earlier versions we defaulted to `ANY`. The secondary reason is that TinkerGraph is often used for subgraphing and not all graphs use a numeric `id`, so `ANY` works really well in those cases by default without any additional change from the user. Perhaps, it's time to change all that....this problem comes up all too often.